# Determine the sender of http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express, web

How do I determine which user has logged in in an express js application? I want to determine who is sending the request in my server program.

Comment: Do your users login to the site?  If so, there should be a login cookie.  If not, then you will need to create a login system so you can identify which user is which.

Answer (score 1):

### MeanJS stack

You can use `req.user`

```
exports.some_method = function(req, res) {
    var user = req.user;
    //do something
};
```

But you have to use `users.requiresLogin` to have persisted user

```
app.route('/model/:modelId').get(users.requiresLogin, my_controller.some_method)
```

It's implementation is pretty simple

```
exports.requiresLogin = function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.status(401).send({
            message: 'User is not logged in'
        });
    }
    next();
};
```

It's session based implementation indeed, but still good. 
That's it

### Pure expressJS

You must use middleware that would detect current user by its cookie
It's more complicated indeed, and you have to write own implementation
But there are plenty of plugins, like passport, that would *validate user* by your fields. Also can serialize into `req.user` and vice versa

But i would strongly recommend to checkout MeanJS stack implementation, it's pretty easy to understand. As the name implies, it's MongoExpressAngularNode, so it's express based stack.

### More

It depends on what kind of auth schema you are using, if it's REST, then you have to pass token in all requests to server, so that server checks db and get's user with corresponding token. If it's sessions based, then you can simple use any session based plugins. But the idea is same, when signing in, serialize user to session table, set cookie, when receiving request take cookie from requester, deserialize from session table, you got user now